# Changing list item color on button click using Java Script?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how can I change all list item color or style with a button using Java Script ?

For example I have following unordered list in my HTML file:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

and a button in my HTML file:

`<button type="button" id="btn"> Click to change all item colors black </button>`

Now when I click on the button it should change the color of all the list items to black from one single click.Example of screenshot below :)

[image: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fmF7.png)]

Comment: how are you currently styling your list

Comment: Please do *not* edit a question to make it less useful; it was edited so that we can see the code you're trying to adjust, as per the "*[mcve]*" guidelines. Speaking of which, please review those, along with "*[ask]*" because you're not sharing sufficient information. Where does your own code break, in what way? What did you try?

Comment: What is the code you use to change the color? And what is the problem with that code?

Comment: Use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit question toolbar to add your markup, JS, and CSS to make a [mcve]. At the moment people are just guessing how you're adding styling to your markup, and writing answers based on those guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the button that reacts to the click event.

```js
const btn =document.getElementById("btn")
btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

})
```

and in the click event callback function write the logic to style the lists

```js
const btn =document.getElementById("btn")
btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    const elements = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName('li')
    // use a for loop to iterate over all the elements of `elements` array and apply the styles
    for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.color = 'black';
    }
})
```

Comment: `getElementById("click"`:  this is wrong. Did you mean `getElementById("element").addEventListener('click', () => ...`?

Comment: Oh my bad, i meant add event listener

Answer (score 1):

A code that will change the color of all `li` elements under the id=`list` when the button is clicked, I hope it will be useful.

```js
var btn=document.getElementById('btn');
var listItems=document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li"); // get 'li' elements under the id="list"
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  for(var li of listItems){ // iterate all 'li' elements to change colors.
    li.style.color='black';
  }
})
```

```css
li{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="btn"> Click to change all item colors black </button>
```

Comment: This changes all the list items red.

Comment: I didn't know the original color so I did it that way, now I gave it a red value at the beginning and updated it to be black when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each element and apply style to each element

```js
let items = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");

document.getElementById('toRed')
.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  for(var li of items){
    li.style.color='red';
  }
});

document.getElementById('toBlue')
.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  for(var li of items){
    li.style.color='blue';
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
</ul>

<button id="toRed">
Change All to Red
</button>

<button id="toBlue">
Change All to Blue
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why haven't you assigned any `id` or `class` attributes to the `<li>` elements so that you could have differentiated which ones you have to work with?

Considering these are the only `li` tags in your HTML page, you can write a function that gets these elements from JavaScript DOM and assign color attributes to the element.

In order to get all elements with tag `li`, we have the `getElementsByTagName()` method.

Also, I have just added few colors to the `li` items myself in your HTML code so as to initially see the items in different color.(Because I don't know how you are getting different colors in the items)

Your HTML Code=>

```
 <ul id="list">
        <font color="red"><li> Item 1 </li></font>
        <font color="green"><li> Item 2 </li></font>
        <font color="blue"><li> Item 3 </li></font>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" onclick='changeColor("black")' id="btn"> Click to change all item colors black </button>
```

The JavaScript function that does the job=>

```
function changeColor(color) {
            let listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
            for(let i=0;i<listItems.length;i++){
                let element = listItems[i].style.color=color;
            }
        }
```

You may have to put this JavaScript code within `<script>` tags or in another `.js` file which you have linked with this HTML page.

Now, you can change the color to whatever you wanted and reuse the method for different colors.

Thanks.

Comment: font tag.... it is not 1999. And that html is invalid.

Comment: Yes @epascarello. I understand font tag is too old for use and I would not have used in my work. But how is the HTML invalid? Just curious to know and I'm also learning.

Comment: font is not a valid child of ul